# Convert this JavaScript to work with multiple songs?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I created this little audio player that plays a randomized intro, a midsection for a song, and then a randomized outro.
Right now it's hardcoded for 1 song. Each song has 3 intros, a midsection, and 3 outros. I want to be able to have a list of songs that is randomly chosen from (like picking at random from an array), so the script will choose a song and change the script (intros and outros and the midsection) accordingly.
I thought about different ways to do this, but I don't want to have a huge number of arrays for every song in the script. How would I go about designing a system like this? demo at [www.saradio.tk/dev.html](http://www.saradio.tk/dev.html) (audio timing only works correctly in Chrome-ACTIVE-TAB AFAIK)

Code:

```
<body onload="checkdif(), loadintro(), loadoutro()">
<audio id="intro" src="" controls preload autoplay></audio>
<audio id="mid" src="radio/Barracuda-mid.ogg" controls preload></audio>
<audio id="outro" src="" controls preload></audio>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="resetradio()">RESET</button>   <span id="timeleft"> n/a </span>

<script>
    var intros = [
        "radio/Barracuda-intro1.ogg",
        "radio/Barracuda-intro2.ogg",
        "radio/Barracuda-intro3.ogg"];

    var outros = [
        "radio/Barracuda-outro1.ogg",
        "radio/Barracuda-outro2.ogg",
        "radio/Barracuda-outro3.ogg"];

    function loadintro() {
        document.getElementById("intro").src = intros[Math.floor(Math.random() * intros.length)];
        document.getElementById("intro").load();
        document.getElementById("intro").play();
    }

    function loadoutro() {
        document.getElementById("outro").src = outros[Math.floor(Math.random() * outros.length)];
        document.getElementById("outro").load();
    }

    x = document.getElementById('intro');
    y = document.getElementById('mid');
    done = false;
    done2 = false;

    function checkdif() {
        if (done) return;
        setTimeout('checkdif()', 5);
        document.getElementById('timeleft').innerHTML = x.duration - x.currentTime;
        if (x.duration - x.currentTime <= 0.09) {
            document.getElementById('mid').play();
            done = true;
            checkdif2();
        }
    }

    function checkdif2() {
        if (done2) return;
        setTimeout('checkdif2()', 5);
        document.getElementById('timeleft').innerHTML = y.duration - y.currentTime;
        if (y.duration - y.currentTime <= 0.09) {
            document.getElementById('outro').play();
            done2 = true;
        }
    }

    function resetradio() {
        done = false;
        done2 = false;
        document.getElementById('mid').pause();
        document.getElementById('mid').currentTime = 0;
        loadintro();
        loadoutro();
        checkdif();
    }

    document.getElementById("outro").addEventListener('ended', resetradio, false)
</script>
</body>
```

PS: I also though about designing the system so it removes the song just played from the list, so it never plays the same song until it has cycled through all other possibles. So it would pick from an array of songs, and when it picks lets say "song x", it will remove "song x" from the array for the next run of random-picking. Just a thought...

## UPDATE: Here is my final implementation of this system: http://saradio.tk/new.html

**If you view the source and watch the console, you'll see that it pulls a random song from the array, then removes that song from the array. This way it does not repeat a song until all songs have been played. Once the loop gets to the last song, the array is restored to the original state.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you say you don't want to have a huge number of arrays, as long as each song has a list of intros and a list of outros, you must somehow "know" about them. You basically have 2 options:

1. make a naming convention system, where all the outros and intros have similar filenames with some suffix
2. specify all intros outros explicitely

For 1. , your data structure could look like this:

```
var intro_suffix = '-intro';
var outro_suffix = '-outro';
var extension = '.ogg';
var songs = [
    {
           base_name: "radio/Barracuda"
        ,  num_intro: 3
        , num_outros: 3
    },
    {
           base_name: "radio/SomeOtherSong"
        ,  num_intro: 3
        , num_outros: 3
    },
];
```

From that once you pick a song, you derive the file names of the intro, main song, and outro. For example:

```
var song = songs[0];
var intro_url = song.name
    + intro_suffix
    + (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * song.num_intros))
    + extension;
var song_url = song.name + extension;
var outro_url = song.name
    + outro_suffix
    + (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * song.num_outros))
    + extension;
```

For 2, your data structure would have to be explicit:

```
var songs = [
    {
             url: "radio/Barracuda.ogg"
        , intros: ["radio/Barracuda-intro1.ogg", "radio/Barracuda-intro2.ogg", "radio/Barracuda-intro3.ogg"]
        , outros: ["radio/Barracuda-outtro1.ogg", "radio/Barracuda-outro2.ogg", "radio/Barracuda-outro3.ogg"]
    },
    {
             url: "radio/SomeOtherSong.ogg"
        , intros: ["radio/foo.ogg", "radio/bar.ogg", "radio/baz.ogg"]
        , outros: ["radio/meh.ogg", "radio/fuuuuu.ogg", "radio/yo.ogg"]
    },
];
```

And then you derive your variables as:

```
var song = songs[0];
var intro_url = song.intros[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.intros.length)];
var song_url = song.url;
var outro_url = song.outros[Math.floor(Math.random() * song.outros.length)];
```

One "advantage" of 2. is that you can ame your files whatever you want

Comment: I am implementing idea #1 as I type this. I had to make the same change you did a few minutes ago (adding 1 to the math.floor so the results are x1-x3 not x0-x2. This method works better for me as I noticed not ALL of the songs have 3 intros or outros, and having that system in place ensures I can simply change the values in the array so the "engine" doesn't produce invalid sources.

Comment: PS: I also added `var mid_suffix = '-mid';` and changed `var song_url = song.name + mid_suffix + extension;` so the correct source **song-mid.ogg** would be used for the mid.

Comment: glad that helped, please upvote or accept the answer it it was useful to you (sorry, that's me being shameless and begging :p)

Comment: Nice! I see you are duplicating the songs data in your resetSong method. Don't do that. Instead, have your songs data immutable, and instead make your program work on a copy of your songs array. Create the copy by calling your resetSongs once at initialization. For info: to make a (shallow) copy of an array, use new_array = old_array.concat();